# .net core API sending array object

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I have student class with array StudentPhones. When i remove StudentPhones property from Student class is working perfectly when post with Postman. But when add StudentPhones property then Postman gives me this error:

{
    "StudentPhones": [
        "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'DataAccess.StudentPhone' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath 'StudentPhones', line 4, position 23."
    ]
}

```
    public class Student
    {
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string StudentSurname { get; set; }
        public StudentPhone StudentPhones { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudentPhone
    {
        public int PhoneType{ get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task<ServiceResult> SaveStudent([FromBody]Student student)
    {
    }
```

How can I post this json? (I am using angular 6 in real, postman is only for example.)

my json

```
{
  "studentName": "test",
  "studentSurname": "test",
  "studentPhones": [
    {
      "phoneType": 1,
      "phoneNumber ": "111111111"
    },
    {
      "phoneType": 2,
      "phoneNumber ": "2222222222"
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: Why don't you have `StudentPhones` declared as an array, or List, of `StudentPhone` in the `Student` class?

Comment: It was careless of me :) . Thanks for your reply. I am so ashamed for this question

Comment: That's okay! If you really want, you can delete the post. It will likely be closed and removed at some point because it was a simple mistake in the code.

Comment: I try delete the question but stackoverflow deny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of phones in your JSON, so instead of `public StudentPhone StudentPhones { get; set; }` in your model, you should have `public List<StudentPhone> StudentPhones { get; set; }`

Comment: You should use a list of StudentPhones 
`public List<StudentPhone> StudentPhones { get; set; }`

Comment: It was careless of me :) . Thanks for your reply. I am so ashamed for this question

Comment: @HasanOzdemir Happens to all of us sometimes. I'll vote your question away.